# How to find a specific row from firestorage array values using if & for function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching an array from FireStorage using typescript. Below is my login.component.ts code . I want to remove the existing code from login:void() function and instead add a code that checks and matches the value of users (usersname and password) from the array "users: User[]" . If the username and password is found then it will proceed otherwise it will go to the else function. The getUsers() function inside ngonInit fetches the users from firestorage

**LOGIN.COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material';
import { UserService } from '../service/user.service';
import { User } from '../models/user';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }
username: string;
password: string;
  ngOnInit() {
    if(localStorage.getItem('logkey')=='1') {
      this.router.navigate(["app1"]);   
    }
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
      //console.log(users);
      this.users = users;
    });
  }
  login() : void {
    if(this.username == 'aayush' && this.password == 'demo'){
     localStorage.setItem('logkey',"1");
     localStorage.setItem('loguser',this.username);
     this.router.navigate(["app1"]);
    }
    else if(this.username == 'admin' && this.password == 'admin'){
     localStorage.setItem('logkey',"1");
     localStorage.setItem('loguser',this.username);
     this.router.navigate(["app1"]);
    }
    else {
      alert("Invalid credentials");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so, `this.users` is an Array? array has an `.includes` method you could use

Comment: yes it is an array. can you please also help me with some code about .includes method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will not recommend to filter user on ui side(as it clearly a security vulnerability) instead you should filter and fetch records again to check if user exist .Still if you want to do so then You can use Array.find or Array.some method to check if user exist.So your code will be like :-

```
var userExist=this.users.some(u=> u.username == this.username && u.password==this.password)
 if(userExist){
     localStorage.setItem('logkey',"1");
     localStorage.setItem('loguser',this.username);
     this.router.navigate(["app1"]);
    }
    else {
//your code
```

[here is an example if you want to filter on api side](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/multi-property-data-filtering-with-firebase-and-angular-4/)